# Iterating over nested dictionary returns only first element

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have this nested dictionary ("dictionary of dictionaries")

```
source = {
    "OuterVal0": {"InnerVal": [10, 21, 96],"InnerVal2": [100, 91, 71]},
    "OuterVal1": {"InnerVal": [21, 19, 76],"InnerVal2": [1, 1, 1]},
    "OuterVal2": {"InnerVal": [1, 1, 96],"InnerVal2": [10, 9, 7]},
    "OuterVal3": {"InnerVal": [0, 2, 6],"InnerVal2": [1, 911, 718]},
    "OuterVal4": {"InnerVal": [12, 13, 9],"InnerVal2": [1000, 910, 701]},
    "OuterVal5": {"InnerVal": [110, 211, 961],"InnerVal2": [10, 911, 918]},     
}
```

And I want to create a new one which would consist of outer keys associated with inner values (see expected output below)
I use this recursive function:

```
def myPrint(d, key=""):
    output = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        i = 0
        if isinstance(v, dict):
          return  myPrint(v, k)
        else:
            for  value in d.values():
                newkey = (f"{i}_{key}")
                output[newkey] = value
                i += 1
    return output
```

But when I try to print that:

```
print(myPrint(source))
```

I get this (only the first dictionary is processed:

```
# {'0_OuterVal0': [10, 21, 96], '1_OuterVal0': [100, 91, 71]}
```

But I would like to have something like this (all dictionaries processed)

```
"""
Expected output
{'0_OuterVal0': [10, 21, 96], '1_OuterVal0': [100, 91, 71]}
{'0_OuterVal1':[21, 19, 76], '1_OuterVal1': [1, 1, 1]}
.
.
.
{'0_OuterVal5':  [110, 211, 961], '1_OuterVal5': [10, 911, 918]}

"""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: This is because after iterating through the 1st element, `return  myPrint(v, k)` executes causing the function to end and it cannot iterate through rest of the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call  `return  myPrint(v, k)` for the first time you compute the values for the first dictionary and then return instead of continuing to the other values in the for loop.

Changing the function to:

```
def myPrint(d, key=""):
    output = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        i = 0
        if isinstance(v, dict):
          output.update(myPrint(v, k))
        else:
            for  value in d.values():
                newkey = (f"{i}_{key}")
                output[newkey] = value
                i += 1
    return output
```

will return a big dictionary, for you example:

```
{'0_OuterVal0': [10, 21, 96], '1_OuterVal0': [100, 91, 71],
 '0_OuterVal1': [21, 19, 76], '1_OuterVal1': [1, 1, 1],
 '0_OuterVal2': [1, 1, 96], '1_OuterVal2': [10, 9, 7],
 '0_OuterVal3': [0, 2, 6], '1_OuterVal3': [1, 911, 718],
 '0_OuterVal4': [12, 13, 9], '1_OuterVal4': [1000, 910, 701],
 '0_OuterVal5': [110, 211, 961], '1_OuterVal5': [10, 911, 918]}
```

However, the function can be nicely packed in a non-recursive way as follow:

```
output = [{f'{ii}_{k}': vv  for (k, v) in source.items() for ii, (kk, vv) in enumerate(v.items())}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output can be obtained more simply as a list comprehension:

```
output = [{f'0_OuterVal{i}': v['InnerVal'], f'1_OuterVal{i}': v['InnerVal2']}
          for i, (k, v) in enumerate(source.items())]
```

This will create a list of dicts with the keys and values you specified.

Comment: This is a good solution for the special case where the inner dictionaries have only two fields but in the general case I do not think it will work

Comment: Why not? The extra "fields" (do you mean keys?) would just be ignored. This code only refers the keys `InnerVal` and `InnerVal2`.

Comment: Also, why do you think it's a "special case"? The question was about this specific input. Why should the answer deal with anything else?

Comment: Yes, but if `"OuterVal0": {"InnerVal": [10, 21, 96],"InnerVal2": [100, 91, 71] , "InnerVal3":[1,2,3]}` then `InnerVal3` will be ignored which is not necessarily wanted

Comment: Then that should be stated in the question. The question didn't mention any possibility of `InnerVal3`.

Comment: Of course, it's possible to handle an arbitrary amount of keys in the inner dict. For example, the dictionary inside the list comprehension could be replaced with a dict comprehension that goes over all the keys. However it might start being tricky to understand for a beginner, thus I want to avoid it unless a generic version is requested in the question.

Comment: I agree that the question is not stating that specifically but a general solution will usually be better than a specifically tailored solution in my opinion. In addition it might help make the  OP grow as a coder :)

Comment: Yep, but then there is also the question of how general you want to be. A really general answer would also add proper error handling, support for missing and malformed keys etc. Listcomps such as above are often a bit too concise for production code, unless the input can be assumed to be perfect (i.e. generated by the computer)...

Answer (score 0):

Following the execution of the code step by step with a debugger would help you :

When you call `myPrint(source)` and enter the for loop, you indeed call your function recursively, but instead of adding the 1st nested dictionary to your output, you use the `return` keyword. so the dictionary created with the 1st key is returned and that's the end of your function.

If the purpose of your function is to print, and that you want to keep your original code structure, you could use this :

```
def myPrint(d, key=""):
    output = {}
    lines = ""
    for k, v in d.items():
        i = 0
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            lines += str(myPrint(v, k)) + '\n'
        else:
            for value in d.values():
                newkey = (f"{i}_{key}")
                output[newkey] = value
                i += 1

    return output if lines == "" else lines
```